# Scala parameter type inference error in SBT (0.7.x vs. 0.11.x)

Tags: scala, sbt

This code compiles only with SBT 0.7.x series (in this case, 0.7.7), but no with SBT 0.11.x series (en this case, 0.11.3). In both cases, using the same Scala 2.9.x series (2.9.1)

It seems that SBT 0.11.3 cannot infer the parameters' types. Nor can Eclipse.
My guess is that there is a problem in the coding. Or is it an SBT regression?

(At the moment, I am using Eclipse 4.2 with the "unstable" version of the Scala plugin. However, I get the same error with Eclipse 3.7 and the "stable" version of the plugin.)

```
// either using the "override" reserved keyword or not, this code will compile with SBT 0.7.7 but not with 11.3


 sealed trait FacetJoin[T1, T1S, T2S] {
    def facetJoin (a: T1S, b: T1S
      , fVals: (T1, T1) => T2S
      , fFacets: (Formula, T1S, T1S, Formula, T1S, T1S) => T2S
      , fBothL: (T1S, Formula, T1S, T1S) => T2S
      , fBothR: (Formula, T1S, T1S, T1S) => T2S
      , fOther: (T1S, T1S) => T2S): T2S
  }
  object FacetJoin {
    implicit object BoolBoolFacetJoin
    extends FacetJoin[Boolean, Formula, Formula] {

// Eclipse complaint for next line: 
//// Multiple markers at this line
////    - only classes can have declared but undefined 
////     members
////    - ':' expected but ',' found.

      override def facetJoin (a, b, fVals, fFacets, fBothL, fBothR, fOther): Formula = {
 ...

// Eclipse complaint for next line: 
//// Multiple markers at this line
////    - identifier expected but '}' 
////     found.
////    - not found: type <error>
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Has this actually anything to do with sbt? Is that code used in an sbt build file? Or do you just use sbt for compilation? In the latter case, it has nothing to do with sbt which just uses the Scala compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
def facetJoin (a, b, fVals, fFacets, fBothL, fBothR, fOther): Formula
```

You cannot define a method without specifying the parameter types in Scala. This couldn't have been compiled by any Scala version. The `...` also indicate that you are leaving out stuff here. Try to provide a fully self contained example (e.g. add `trait Formula`). With the types put in, it compiles without problems:

```
trait Formula

sealed trait FacetJoin[T1, T1S, T2S] {
  def facetJoin (a: T1S, b: T1S
    , fVals: (T1, T1) => T2S
    , fFacets: (Formula, T1S, T1S, Formula, T1S, T1S) => T2S
    , fBothL: (T1S, Formula, T1S, T1S) => T2S
    , fBothR: (Formula, T1S, T1S, T1S) => T2S
    , fOther: (T1S, T1S) => T2S): T2S
}
object FacetJoin {
  implicit object BoolBoolFacetJoin
  extends FacetJoin[Boolean, Formula, Formula] {

  override def facetJoin (a: Formula, b: Formula
    , fVals: (Boolean, Boolean) => Formula
    , fFacets: (Formula, Formula, Formula, Formula, Formula, Formula) => Formula
    , fBothL: (Formula, Formula, Formula, Formula) => Formula
    , fBothR: (Formula, Formula, Formula, Formula) => Formula
    , fOther: (Formula, Formula) => Formula): Formula = sys.error( "TODO" )
    }
 }
```